# Multi-module subproject dependent on each other in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a question regarding multi-module sub project in Gradle, can sub projects depend on each other?

For example the following project:

```
root
|___ project1
|___ project2
|___ project3
```

Can project1 and project2 depend on each other?

in `build.gradle` of `project1`:

```
dependencies {
       compile project(':project2')
}
```

in `build.gradle` of `project2`:

```
dependencies {
       compile project(':project1')
}
```

I am new to gradle, does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it work ?

**Short answer** : no

**Detailed answer** :

It's not specific to Gradle and it's called [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). It's bad and it prevents the compilation. `project1` needs `project2` so it will require `project2` to be built before. `project2` needs `project1` so it will require `project1` to be built before. Do you see the issue ?

There is many ways to solve circular dependencies, depending of your architecture. In your simple example, maybe `project1` and `project2` should belong to the same project.